# Что делать, если в принятых ответах есть ошибки?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, принятые-ответы

Изучая термины C#, такие как «переопределение» и «перегрузка», я обнаружил несколько принятых ответов, которые вызвали сомнения. В качестве примера приведу два таких ответа:

- *"следует перегрузить метод `OnModelCreating` - и написать там примерно следующее"*
  [27 май '15 в 15:53](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/426555/201326), Pavel Mayorov, 9,255
- *"базовый класс всех типов-значений, перегружает метод `Equals`"*
  [30 сен '15 в 0:01](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454619/201326), VladD, 74k

Сомнения возникли из-за того, что в контексте ответов речь идет о виртуальных методах [Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) и [OnModelCreating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx), и использовать термин перегрузка в данном контексте неправильно.

Я решил уточнить, задав вопрос. Мне [ответили](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/490787/201326), что термины «переопределение» и «перегрузка» по смыслу — это абсолютно разные вещи. В комментарии сказали, что термины в ответах использованы неправильно. Получается, что в принятых ответах содержатся ошибки, и слово «перегружать» надо заменить на слово «переопределить».

Как следует поступить в такой ситуации?

Comment: написать комментарий автору ответа, либо написать свой собственный ответ. Неправильные ответы можете и заминусовать, но только напишите причину минуса

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что мне надо создать свой ответ с исправленной копией существующего ответа с ошибкой? Что касается минусов, то мне такая возможность недоступна.

Comment: С новыми ответами поосторожнее. См. ответ.

Comment: Мы с VladD уже отвечали на очень похожий вопрос: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/961/181472

Answer (score 7):

Зависит от того, насколько вас это парит и насколько вы в этом разбираетесь.

1. *"Хочешь сделать что-то хорошо, сделай это сам"*. Вы можете предложить правку, исправляющую термин на нужный. Минимум зависимостей и времени.
2. Вы можете поставить ответу минус и указать в комментарии, где видите ошибку. Не забудьте снять минус, когда ответ поправят, и поставить плюс, чтобы мотивировать автора реагировать на такие случаи.
3. Если всё настолько плохо, что ответ неверный в корне (и исправление конкретно этой технической неточности не сделает его верным), можно опубликовать новый ответ. Но убедитесь, что он всё же **другой**, в противном случае сообщество может отреагировать даже **отрицательно**, посчитав, что вы набираете репутацию за счёт чужих ответов.

Но **не нужно** поднимать *тревогу*. Они не предназначены для привлечения внимания к постам, содержащим фактические ошибки и технические неточности.

Comment: Можно и без минуса обойтись.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно, если это не *ошибка*, а скорее *неточность*, которую достаточно отразить в комментарии. Но содержательные части комментариев неплохо бы вносить прямо в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за абзац о тревогах. В последнее время нередки случаи.

Answer (score 6):

Если вы видите использование ошибочного термина - например, "перегрузить" вместо "переопределить", считаете что это влияет на общую читабельность ответа и при этом точно знаете правильный термин, который должен быть использован - предложите правку к ответу.